# Don't use asdf if there is no .tool-versions file?

Tags: asdf, asdf-vm

I installed node.js:

```
brew install node
```

I also installed asdf with node.js plugin. Is there any way to use node.js installed via Homebrew globally if there is no `.tool-versions` file?

Right now I am getting an error if this file does not exist:

```
No version is set for command node
Consider adding one of the following versions in your config file at
nodejs 19.0.0
nodejs 19.0.1
nodejs 19.1.0
nodejs 19.2.0
```

I don't want to use asdf globally. Just for few projects.

Comment: As a work-around, it is possible to create a `~/.tool-versions` file with a one line content `nodejs system`. According to the [documentation](https://asdf-vm.com/manage/configuration.html#tool-versions), this "causes asdf to passthrough to the version of the tool on the system that is not managed by asdf". Which should have a similar effect to what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Using Bash you can use [PROMPT_COMMAND](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x264.html) to check if the `.tool-versions` file exists in the current folder and add or remove `.asdf` folders from the `PATH`.

Just add this to your `.bashrc`:

```bash
conditional_asdf() {
  if [ ! -f "$PWD/.tool-versions" ]; then
    export PATH=`echo $PATH | sed -E 's/(.*)\.asdf([^:]*)://'`
  else
    export PATH="${HOME}/.asdf/shims:${HOME}/.asdf/bin:${PATH}"
  fi
}

PROMPT_COMMAND="conditional_asdf; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't *completely* answer your question, but I've stumbled upon the same problem and found the following workaround for using `asdf` with *some* projects, but not others:

Instead of sourcing the asdf scripts for every shell, I wrap them in a condition. `~/.bashrc` (on Linux & Bash, in your case it will probably be `${ZDOTDIR:-~}/.zshrc`) might then contain the following:

```bash
# ASDF tool version manager
if [ -n "$WITH_ASDF" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh";
    . "$HOME/.asdf/completions/asdf.bash";
else
    alias asdf="WITH_ASDF='true' /bin/bash";
fi;
```

With this asdf is initially not loaded at all and I can use NVM like before (or, in your case, the system's nodeJS). By simply typing `asdf` into the terminal, a new shell is invoked *with asdf loaded*. To return to the non-asdf shell a simple `exit` (or Ctrl+D) will do.

```bash
$> which node
/home/andi/.nvm/versions/node/v16.19.0/bin/node

$> asdf
$> which node
/home/andi/.asdf/shims/node

$> exit
```

*(Obviously you'll have to adjust the above for your specific environment, i.e. Homebrew and probably ZSH, based on [these code samples from asdf's getting started page](https://asdf-vm.com/guide/getting-started.html#_3-install-asdf).)*

If you prefer, you could turn this principle around and make asdf the default (with some extra steps included that only apply if you use NVM) (untested):

```bash
# ASDF tool version manager
if [ -z "$NO_ASDF" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh";
    . "$HOME/.asdf/completions/asdf.bash";
    # This alias could also be called "nvm"
    alias noasdf="NO_ASDF='true' /bin/bash";
# This "else" block is optional if you only want to use the system's nodeJS
else
    # Node version manager
    export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm";
    [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm;
    [ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion";  # This loads nvm bash_completion
fi;
```

You could probably build on that and have a script auto-evaluate whether a `.tool-versions` file exists in the cwd at any given time and then automatically start or exit the shell, but that's quite a bit beyond my shell-fu.